# How do I add a csv file to a dictionary as a value

Tags: python, list, csv, dictionary

I have created a dictionary `dataset = dict()` and I have created a list columns:

```
colums = ["date", "day", "month", "year", "cases", "deaths", "countriesAndTerritories","countryTerritoryId", "countryTerritoryCode", "population2019", "continent", "cumulativeper1000002Weeks"]
```

Now I have put the columns as the key and I want a csv file as the value.
This is the code:

```
dataset = dict()
for h in colums:
    dataset[h] = ""
print(dataset)
```

and the outcome:

```
{'date': '', 'day': '', 'month': '', 'year': '', 'cases': '', 'deaths': '', 'countriesAndTerritories': '', 'countryTerritoryId': '', 'countryTerritoryCode': '', 'population2019': '', 'continent': '', 'cumulativeper1000002Weeks': ''}
```

However I want to put a csv file into the dictionary as the value

```
for row in reader:
    dataset[h] = row
print(dataset)
```

which gives

```
{'date': '', 'day': '', 'month': '', 'year': '', 'cases': '', 'deaths': '', 'countriesAndTerritories': '', 'countryTerritoryId': '', 'countryTerritoryCode': '', 'population2019': '', 'continent': '', 'cumulativeper1000002Weeks': ['25/09/2020', '25', '9', '2020', '0', '0', 'Afghanistan', 'AF', 'AFG', '38041757', 'Asia', '1.57195684']}
```

What I want to happen is `{'date': '25/09/2020', 'day': '25', 'month': '9' ...... }`

Note: the code is

```
import csv
def read_dataset() -> List[Dict[str,str]]:
    with open('covid-19.csv', 'r') as file:
        reader = csv.reader(file)
        no_head = next(reader, None)
        colums = ["date", "day", "month", "year", "cases", "deaths", "countriesAndTerritories",
              "countryTerritoryId", "countryTerritoryCode", "population2019", "continent", "cumulativeper1000002Weeks"]
        dataset = dict()
        for h in colums:
            dataset[h] = ""
        for row in reader:
            dataset[h] = row
            return dataset
dataset = read_dataset()
print(dataset)
```

Answer (score 1):

Three-liner specific for your case (needs `python -m pip install requests`), produces list of dicts, each dict is a row in the form you wanted:

[Try it online!](https://repl.it/@moytrage/StackOverflow64077751#main.py)

```
import io, csv, requests
bytes_data = requests.get('https://opendata.ecdc.europa.eu/covid19/casedistribution/csv').content
print(list(csv.DictReader(io.StringIO(bytes_data.decode('utf-8')), delimiter = ',')))
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest checking out the [DictReader](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.DictReader) available in the Python `csv` module. I think it may save you a lot of trouble by doing what you need automatically.

I suspect your code could be rewritten as:

```py
import csv
from typing import Dict, List, Iterable


def read_dataset(filename: str, custom_headers: Iterable[str] = None) -> List[Dict[str, str]]:
    with open(filename, 'r') as file:
        reader = csv.DictReader(file, fieldnames=custom_headers)
        return list(reader)

my_headers = [
    'date',
    'day',
    'month',
    'year',
    'cases',
    'deaths',
    'countriesAndTerritories',
    'countryTerritoryId',
    'countryTerritoryCode',
    'population2019',
    'continent',
    'cumulativeper1000002Weeks',
]

dataset = read_dataset('covid-19.csv', my_headers)
print(dataset)
```

Disclaimer: I have not tried running the above code.

This assumes that the csv file you are reading does not have a header row already or that you want to rename the fields with custom names.

Answer (score 0):

From the code you posted it is not clear how your file looks like.
Assuming it has a single line, like

```
'25/09/2020','25','9','2020','0','0','Afghanistan','AF','AFG','38041757','Asia','1.57195684'
```

You could do something like

```
colums = ["date", "day", "month", "year", "cases", "deaths", "countriesAndTerritories", "countryTerritoryId", "countryTerritoryCode", "population2019", "continent", "cumulativeper1000002Weeks"]

with open('untitled.txt', 'r') as file:
    fcontent = file.read().split(',')

for idx, c in enumerate(colums):
    dataset[c] = fcontent[idx]
```

Comment: I got the file from https://data.europa.eu/euodp/nl/data/dataset/covid-19-coronavirus-data and it has many lines. Thank you for the respond though, I will try it out

Comment: @Bows I didn't had a look at your file but you might want to edit your question and post a portion of it, e.g. the first 10 lines. In any case, I would then suggest to use `pandas` since you seem to work with time series data.